# Delete an element in array using recursion in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, recursion

So, here's my code:

```
int *recursDelete(int arr[], int n, int pos, int i){
    if(i<n){
        arr[pos-1]=arr[i+1];
        recursDelete(arr, n, pos+1, i++);
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

I'm trying to copy every element from the given position to the left, and then just return the array. I don't get what is going wrong. Also I'm trying to remove the `i`from the parameter, but if I do that and put `i=0` inside the function, then `i` is always gonna be 0.

Comment: ```arr[poz-1]``` - I assume you meant ```pos``` ?

Comment: @sj95126 oh yeah, I edited it later when posting.

Comment: @AndersK by shifting it to the end, returning the pointer of the array, and then printing it in `main()` using a `for` loop with `n-2`

Comment: the i++ is completely meaningless, it increments after it is passed to the function, maybe you meant ++i

Comment: When using recursion like that shown, using the `++` operator at all is pointless, since the value of `i` is never used again withing the same stack frame, so modifying it has no effect. `i + 1` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int  *recursDelete(int arr[], int n, int poz);
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p= recursDelete(arr, 5, 3, 0);
    
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        printf("%d", *p);
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int *recursDelete(int arr[], int n, int poz){
    if(n!=0){
        arr[poz-1]=arr[poz];
        n--
        recursDelete(arr, n, poz+1);
    }
    else{
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for the tips!

Comment: try deleting the last element

Comment: @AndersK yeah, I did it, by using `n!=0` and decrementing `n` inside `if`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the edge cases. Something like this should work:

```
void deleteElement(int* ar, int pos, int cur, int maxLen)
{
  if (cur < maxLen)
  {
    if ( cur == maxLen - 1 )
    {
      ar[cur] = 0; // last
      return;
    }
    else if ( cur > pos - 1 )
    {
      ar[cur] = ar[cur + 1];
    }
    deleteElement(ar, pos, ++cur, maxLen);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int ar[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  int cur = 0;
  deleteElement(ar, 0, cur, 5);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    printf("%3d", ar[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool found=false;
int size1;
void delete1(int arr[],int x,int key,int size){
 if(x==-1){
        size1--;
     return;
 } 
 delete1(arr,x-1,key,size);
 if(arr[x]==key){
     found=true;
 }
 if(found==true &&x<size-1){
     arr[x]=arr[x+1];
 }
}
int main() {
    cout<<"enter the size: ";
    cin>>size1;
    int key;
    cout<<"enter the elment that you want to delete: ";
    cin>>key;
   int array[size1]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};  
    delete1(array,size1-1,key,size1);
    if(found){
       for(int i=0; i<size1; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<"\t";
         }  
    }else{
        cout<<"no such elment";
    }
    return 0;

}
// this will work
```

Comment: this is c++ code